# How to implement custom implementation of method?

Tags: swift, closures, protocols

I'm drawing a blank for some reason.. If I want to make a bunch of objects from a class, but I want each instance to have its own unique implementation of a certain method, how would I do this?

For example:

```
class MyClass {
    var name: String
    
    func doSomething() { 
        // Each object would have custom implementation of this method, here.
    }
}
```

Do I provide each object with its own closure during initialization, and then call that closure in the `doSomething()` method? I'm trying to figure out the correct or "Swiftly" way to do this. I'm also thinking along the lines of something with protocols, but I can't seem to figure out how to go about this.

Comment: "Do I provide each object with its own closure during initialization, and then call that closure in the doSomething() method?" Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I provide each object with its own closure during initialization, and then call that closure in the doSomething() method

Yes. That is extremely common and eminently Swifty. Incredibly miminalistic example:

```
struct S {
    let f:()->()
    func doYourThing() { f() }
}
let s = S { print("hello") }
let s2 = S { print("goodbye" )}
s.doYourThing() // hello
s2.doYourThing() // goodbye
```

Giving an object a settable method instance property is very, very easy and common. It doesn't *have* to be provided during initialization — you might set this property later on, and a lot of built-in objects work that way too.

That, after all, is all you're doing when you create a data task with [`dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask). You are creating a data task and handing it a function which it stores, and which it will call when it has performed the actual networking.

Comment: There's no need to have the method call the property.

struct S {
    let doYourThing: () -> Void
}

Answer (score 1):

I think there're many ways to do it.

**In case of Base class + some sub-classes** (e.g. `Animal`, subclassed by `Dog`, `Cat`, etc), you can do this:

First of all it's a good idea to define a protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   func doSomething()
}
```

Also provide a default implementation, which throws a fatal error if a class doesn't override that method:

```
extension MyProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        fatalError("You must override me")
    }
}
```

Now your base class confirms the protocol thanks to default implementation. But it will throw a fatal error at runtime:

```
class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    // conformant
}
```

Child class, however, will run correctly as long as it overrides this function:

```
class MyOtherClass: MyClass {

    func doSomething() {
        print("Doing it!")
    }
}
```

You could also move fatal error into base class, and not do any extension implementation.

**In case of many instances of the same Class**, that solution makes no sense. You can use a very simple callback design:

```
typealias MyDelegate = () -> Void

class MyClass {

    var delegate: MyDelegate?

    func doSomething() {
        delegate?()
    }
}

let x = MyClass()
x.delegate = {
    print("do it!")
}
x.doSomething()

// Or you can use a defined function
func doIt() {
    print("also doing it")
}
x.delegate = doIt
x.doSomething()
```

It can also be that you re looking for [Strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy), or [Template pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method). Depends on your usage details.

Comment: So each object will basically have it's own subclass then?

Comment: Depends what level of differences are you talking about... e.g. if you have `Dog` and `Cat` and `Bird` - yes; if you have 1000 `Birds`, then of course makes no sense to have them subclassed. This is why I said there are many options.

Comment: Let's assume I have 1000 birds where each has its own custom implementation of a certain method. Everything else is the same.

Comment: Changed the answer to answer that question. Hard to say though without a specific problem in hand - so many ways.

Comment: Thank you, the new part (2nd half) of your answer is what I was looking for. I just wasn't sure if using closures was the right way to do this, but it seems that it is! Thanks again.